# Как красиво вывести таблицу, ровно по полям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Таблица будет представлена в питоне как список с кортежами внутри.
Соответственно все поля разные и в некоторых до фига символов, когда я вывожу её на экран всё плывёт:

```
for i in tabl():
    for j in i:
        # print(str(j).ljust(20), end="\t")
        print(j, end="\t")

    print()
```

Вот это получаю на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описанолдие изображения]

Как красиво вывести таблицу, ровно по полям?

Как надо правильно её выводить, что и лишних отступов не было, и длинные поля не толкали соседние?

(В процессе написания вопроса узнал про pandas. Если не сложно, в интернете конечно полно уроков по нему, но вот с лету не понятно, там много функций, но мне нужна одна, подскажите если не сложно про мой случай. Это когда есть один список состоящий из кортежей.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/ 
супер решение

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]

x.add_row(["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]

x.add_row(
    [
        ["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5],
        ["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4],
        ["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7],
        ["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5],
        ["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8],
        ["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9],
        ["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4]
    ]
)

print(x)
```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]